# Use lightning-record-form with object Layout to display record

Tags: permissions, lightning-record-form

I'm currently having some issues with displaying a record of a custom object

This occurs when a user that only has read access accesses this page - I'm currently trying to use lightning-record-form to display in the specific object layout - I'm able to get the record data and information through Apex and I have the Id and all from that as well

```
<lightning-record-form
    record-id={recordId}
    object-api-name={objectType}
    layout-type={layoutType}
    columns="1"
    mode="readonly"
>
```

I wasn't able to find a clear answer if lightning-record-form can work in readonly mode if the user has read access to the object but not edit/create access

[image]